# combining two DFs with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DFs that I want to 'merge'

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 1], 'c2': [3, 3]})

A

Out[4]:
   c1  c2
0   1   3
1   1   3

B = pd.DataFrame({'c0': [0, 0], 'c2': [2, 2]})

B

Out[6]:
   c0  c2
0   0   2
1   0   2
```

I want to get a new df that has the columns from B and columns from A that are not in B (as in dict.update), like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'c0': [0, 0], 'c1': [1, 1], 'c2': [2, 2]})

Out[12]:
   c0  c1  c2
0   0   1   2
1   0   1   2
```

**how can I do that in one line?**

does not work:

1. `A.update(B)`
2. `A.join(B)`
3. `B.combine_first(A)` works in this example but does funny things when nans are in the picture.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) to get the columns in `A` that are not in `B`, then you can [`combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) dataframe `B` with columns in `A` that are not in `B`:

```
c = A.columns.difference(B.columns)
B.combine_first(A[c])
```

---

```
   c0   c1  c2
0   0  1.0   2
1   0  1.0   2
```

Comment: As I said, combine_first does funny things when nan are in the picture.

B['c2'].loc[0] = np.nan

B.combine_first(A)

Out[28]: 
   c0   c1  c2
0   0  1.0   2
1   0  1.0   2

Comment: IMO This should work fine..Not sure what you mean by `funny things`..Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help?

```
>>> df=pd.concat([A,B], axis=1).T.drop_duplicates().T

>>> df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
   c0  c1  c2
0   0   1   2
1   0   1   2
```

Comment: Yes but it's not really self explainable.. I can you use drop and then join - nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
res = A.assign(**B.to_dict('series'))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   c1  c2  c0
0   1   2   0
1   1   2   0
```